# How to break lines of a html tag with attributes (ESLint rules)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Due to ESLint rules I am trying to break lines of a html tag with attributes (and ternary) but I can't get it working. Does anyone know how to do it? What is the correct way to break these lines?

Edit: With mouse over it says "Expected indentation of 16 space characters but found 14.eslintreact/jsx-indent-props" , but when I put on correct identation , it says "Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 16.eslintindent".

```
        {
          cardTrunfo
            ? <div
              className="card__super"
              data-type="card"
              data-color="black"
              data-code="0001"
            >
              Card Name
            </div>
            : ''
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Put your mouse over the lines with red. What do they say is the problem?

Comment: With mouse over it says "Expected indentation of 16 space characters but found 14.eslintreact/jsx-indent-props" , but when I put on correct identation , it says "Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 16.eslintindent".

Comment: Can you try this? https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1679

Comment: @J-007 actually I can't simply change or edit rules because it comes from a project that I am working in. So I have to solve it on code itself.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you probabbly have empty spaces on the previus line...
Put evrything back together on a single line and format it once again.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but this might help someone out. In this example you can break out multiple lines of code by wrapping the JSX in parentheses:

```
{
  cardTrunfo
    ? (
      <div
        className="card__super"
        data-type="card"
        data-color="black"
        data-code="0001"
      >
        Card Name
      </div>
    )
    : ''
}
```